# Make a design mobile and different resolution compatible

Tags: jquery, html, css, fluid-layout

I've created a design that is split in the middle by a diagonal vertical line. There is text on each side of it which I would like to be vertically and horizontally centered regardless of which device is being used to view it.  The design is black on one side and white on the other, therefore, the text color need to change as well.  I cannot figure out how to make this adjust to different resolutions and devices where the text is always vertically centered. I'm willing to use jQuery or convert this to an image if I could figure out how to make this work.

http://jsfiddle.net/dw4Cj/7/

----------------------HTML--------------------

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="right"></div>
    <div class="content" id="left-content">
        <h1> Designer </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="right-content">         
        <h1> Developer </h1>
    </div>
 </div>
```

---------------------CSS-------------------------

```
#right {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
     height: 10000px;
     left: -851px;
     position: fixed;
     top: -150px;
     transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
     transform: rotate(10deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
     width: 710px;
}

#right-content {
     position: fixed;
     margin: 0 0 0 703px;
     top: 40px;
}

#left-content {
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    top: 40px;
    width: 574px;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 260px;
}

 #left {
     float: right;
     margin-right: 40px;
 }
```

Comment: You should define everything in percentages.

Comment: if you look at this particular design, you will see that its very difficult to make it work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a gradient to create the background, I've created an example for you here:

```
/* HTML */
<body>
    <p class="center-vertical">Designer <span class="black">Developer</span></p>
</body>


/* CSS */
body, html {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-15deg, #000 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-15deg, #000 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -linear-gradient(-15deg, #000 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
}

p {
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;
word-spacing: 80px;
}

.black {
color: #000;
}

/* JS */
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var centerVerticaly = function() {
    var marginTop = $('body').height() / 2;

        $('.center-vertical').css({
            marginTop: marginTop
        });
};

    $(window).bind("load resize", function(){
        centerVerticaly();
    });

    centerVerticaly();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LFGGV/

It's lacking the shadow that you have in the middle of the jsfiddle you posted but you can create that by adding more breakpoints in the gradient.

I did choose to center the text with the help of jQuery, there might be a better way of doing this but it works.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this functionality - can you show me how I would add a shadow?

Comment: I did this: background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-15deg, #000 49.3%, #7d7d7d 1%, #fff 49.7%, #fff 100%);